# Substituir caractere por função PHP

Tags: php

Tenho que fazer um calculo baseado em 2 coisas:

1 - O valor que o usuário informar

2 - A conta base que tenho cadastrada no banco

Tenho a conta base: **5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^(0.0001)-5129.6906**

Onde está **{{INPUT}}** é o valor que o usuário informar no input, até ai consigo substituir **{{INPUT}}** pelo valor com a função `str_replace`. O problema maior está em "**^**" que significa "Potência" e para isso o PHP precisa de uma função para calcular. O que preciso é pegar o valor que está depois do "**^**" entre parenteses.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `substring` do php, dessa forma:

```
$conta = "5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^(0.0001)-5129.6906";
$primeiro = strpos($conta, "(");
$segundo = strpos($conta, ")");
$valor = substr($conta, $primeiro + 1, $segundo - $primeiro - 1);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/VnkR8V).

Ou fazer com o `Regex`:

```
$conta = "5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^(0.0001)-5129.6906";
preg_match("/\(([^\]]*)\)/", $conta, $valor);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nHe8qK).

Comment: Obrigado @Francisco .. Sua Regex funcionou perfeitamente. Você conseguiria me explicar detalhamente o que cada item da regex sua faz ? (só caso conseguir mesmo)

Comment: Tem um site que gera a regex por você, é só saber o básico. [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Comment: você poderia me ajudar mais uma vez? Tenho um último calculo que está assim **(({{price}}+625.5175)/637.3620)^5963.7532** e a potência agora está no final e sem parenteses, qual seria a Regex pra pegar somente os valores ?

Comment: Ficaria assim: `preg_match("/[\^](.*)\./", $conta, $valor);`

Comment: até funciona só que ele não pega os decimais, ou seja, ele pega só **5963** e não **5963.7532**

Comment: Ahh, pensei que o ponto estava multiplicando kkk, brisei. Sendo assim, faça `preg_match("/[\^](.*)/", $conta, $valor);`.

Comment: Deu certo, agora só deu um pau no primeiro que você me ajudou pq tinha que ter os parenteses pra sequenciar o calculo certo. A formula é: **(5149.3074*({{INPUT}}^(0.0001)))-5129.6906** ta com parenteses a mais e a Regex está trazendo alguns parenteses.

Comment: Para pegar o de mair importancia (contado com os parenteses) faça assim: `preg_match("/\(([0-9.]+)\)/", $conta, $valor);` Caso essa conta mude sempre, recomendo que faça um algoritmo para se adequar.

Answer (score 1):

Usando um REGEX mais simples:

```
\(([0-9.]+)\)
```

Isso irá permitir qualquer caractere entre 0 até 9 (`0-9`) e pontos (`.`), neste caso ele iria permitir um `0...123`. Mas, não iria pegar qualquer `()` adicional. Entretanto, se quiser apenas que exista um único ponto (ou nenhum) pode utilizar:

```
\(([0-9]+?(\.[0-9]+)?)\)
```

Em geral ele poderá pegar todos os números antes de `.`, se existir, e também os números após o `.`, se também existir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As `\(` e `\.` são para escapar, uma vez que os `()` e o `.` é usado no REGEX para outros casos.

---

Testes:

```
5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^(0.0001)-5129.6906 =>               0.0001
(5149.3074*({{INPUT}}^(0.0001)))-5129.6906 =>           0.0001
(5149.3074*({{INPUT}}^(((((((((0.0001)))))-5129.6906 => 0.0001
5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^(1)-5129.6906 =>                    1
5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^((((((1))))))-5129.6906 =>          1
5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^((((1)))))-5129.6906 =>             1
5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^((((1....123)))))-5129.6906 =>      Não encontrado
```

[Teste isto](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17774faeccd7b3ada618c224a3d9d1866fd952d7)

Answer (score 0):

Expressão regular:   [ideone](https://ideone.com/aqvNo6)

```
$conta = "5149.3074*{{INPUT}}^(0.0001)-5129.6906";
preg_match('^\((.*)\)^', $conta, $match);
print $match[1];
```

O  circunflexo  marca o começo de uma linha. `^\(` significa que a o começo deve ser pelo parentesis `(`, a barra invertida serve para escapar o `(` já que este tem uma função em REGEX. Os parênteses definem um grupo, e seu conteúdo pode ser visto como um bloco na expressão `(...)` - indica o início e o fim de um grupo respectivamente.

```
.   ponto       um caractere qualquer

*   asterisco   zero, um ou mais
```

ou seja, dentro dos parenteses podemos ter tantos caracteres quantos existirem.

Sobre a função  [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

1. O primeiro parâmetro é a expressão regular.  `^\((.*)\)^`
2. O segundo parâmetro é a string onde pesquisaremos a expressão.  `$conta`
3. O terceiro parâmetro é um array que armazenará o termo que casou   `($matches)`.

Answer (score 0):

Opa.
 Acredito que está buscando a função de exponencial a pow.  `var_dump(pow(2, 8)); // int(256)`

Retira de [função pow documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)